# ngx_slab_alloc() failed: no memory in SSL session shared cache "le_nginx_SSL"

Tags: ssl, nginx, runtime-error, lets-encrypt, certbot

ngx_slab_alloc() failed: no memory in SSL session shared cache "le_nginx_SSL"

This error is logged in nginx error.logs and it is continuously updating the error log file with this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in file /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf

I commented out the line:

```
ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:1m;
```

That seems to have fixed it.

I found this solution [here](https://thisinterestsme.com/cache-le_nginx_ssl/).